# OutOfMemoryException While adding list of Markers on Map | Xamarin | Android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, out-of-memory, google-maps-markers

I'm working on mobile application where I'm using `Android Map API v2`. This app has global weather info and has lots of features related to **Sea** and **Land** weather parameters **e.g** *Wind, Cloud, Rain, Pressure, Temperature, Wave, Swell.*

As I mentioned; app has weather parameters, so to visualize these parameters on map I'm using `Markers` which  seems working fine for for every parameters; I have set of icons for every parameters that I'm adding as `Marker` on the map.

My problem is that I'm getting `OutOfMemoryException` while plotting more then one parameters on the map. I'm aware about `Bitmap` and its processing but still struggling to find best way to remove this `OutOfMemoryException` while plotting large amount of data on map.

One more thing is happening with `Markers` and that is while I'm  zooming map icon goes small instead large.

This what I'm doing to plot icons/markers on map:

```
    void CloudPlot()
    {
        var tempMarkers = new List<Marker>();
        int cloudItemCount = 0, i = 0;
        var data = GribReader.Instance.WeatherRequest.CloudRequest;
        cloudItemCount = data.Count;

        while (cloudItemCount > 0)
        {
            var cloudData = data[i];

            Bitmap cloudBitmap = RotateBitmap(-1, GetCloudIcon(cloudData.ValueData));
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                var cloudMarker = mwGoogleMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .SetPosition(new LatLng(cloudData.Latitude + 0.3, cloudData.Longitude + 0.4))
                                            .SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(cloudBitmap))); //Cloud icon
                tempMarkers.Add(cloudMarker);
            });

            i++;
            cloudItemCount--;
            if (cloudItemCount == 0)
            {
                i = 0;
                ProgressCount--;
                //Interlocked.Decrement(ref _progressCount);
                if (VisibleParametrs.ContainsKey(MWParameters.CloudCover))
                    VisibleParametrs.Remove(MWParameters.CloudCover);

                VisibleParametrs.Add(MWParameters.CloudCover, tempMarkers);
            }
        }
        if (cloudItemCount == 0)
            ProgressCount--;
    }
```

Following to Rotate bitmap and reduce size:

```
    public Bitmap RotateBitmap(float angle, int windIcon)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (angle > -1)
            matrix.PostRotate(angle);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.InSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, windIcon, options);
        return Bitmap.CreateBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, matrix, true);
    }
```

I'm getting following result after plotting cloud and wind icons on map (Without zoom):

[image]

**Do we have a best approach to remove** `OutOfMemoryException`?

Also; What we can do to make Markers icons large while zooming map?

Comment: Can you add your stack trace to the question?

Comment: I have added `StackTrace` now. Thanks!

Comment: You should definitively surround your bitmaps in `using`s to dispose and free up the memory they used when they are out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the ***CloudPlot*** function are you sure you are decreasing the value of the ***cloudItemCount*** variable? Becasue I do not see that in the codes you have posted. If not then it is going to be an infinite loop and cause the *OutOfMemoryException*.